# Sending computer info to discord bot

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, bots, raspberry-pi3, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that sends my computer (Raspberry Pi 3) info to my discord bot.

I've tried searching the same question but can't find anything.

My bot is currently working on the Raspberry Pi and have Node.JS installed.

How would I try and accomplish this?

Comment: You say your bot is working. Can you show your code so far and explain which "computer info" you want to send?

Comment: I just wanted to send small things like wifi strength, uptime, and the current time (of where the bot is located).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Node.js documentation on the [`os`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) module. You might find the "info" you're looking for accessible through it.

> The `os` module provides operating system-related utility methods and properties. It can be accessed using:
>
> ```js
> const os = require('os');
> ```